# Rounding to nearest integer symbol in Latex

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

There are some threads here, in which it is explained how to use `\lceil \rceil \lfloor \rfloor`.

But generally, in math, there is a sign that looks like a combination of ceil and floor, which means `round`, aka nearest integer.

Is there a way to draw this sign in Latex's math mode?

Comment: You mean square brackets with/out space in the middle?

Comment: Yes, generally, but just square brackets do not take into account the width of the expression they contain, their width is fixed and sometimes makes them look like regular brackets that are put so you know what expression to compute first

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the width of the expression they contain".

Comment: Related: [Notation for rounding function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879205/15142)

Comment: $[\sum_{i=0}^{n}{blabla}]$ makes it look strange, simply surrounded by brackets. The brackets do not adapt their width to the long expression

Comment: I generally think of "width" as right-left, whereas most questions about adapting size are looking for top-bottom, which I would call "height".  Could you clarify which you mean?  Also, the only way I know that `lceil` et.al. adapt to the middle is by using `\left` or `\bigl`.  But this works just fine on `[`.  So I'm not sure what adapting you want to occur.

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know `\left` and `\right` were needed. Posting an answer for next people looking for it

Comment: Rounding to the nearest integer is not well defined, because one doesn't know what to do with 1/2 and, in general, with k+1/2. Apparently there's no consensus about a notation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `mathtools` package has a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command which lets you define such macros. I defined a `\nint` command which encloses its argument between `\lfloor`  and `\rceil`. The starred version adds a pair of implicit `\left`...`\right`, but you may fine-tune the delimiters size using one of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\nint}\lfloor\rceil

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert

\begin{document}

    \[ \nint{x}\qquad \nint*{\sqrt{x^2 + \mfrac13}}\qquad\nint[\Big]{\sqrt{x^2}} = \abs{x}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\nint*` if you want it to automatically resize itself, or use `\newcommand{\nint}[1]{\ensuremath\left\lfloor#1\right\rceil}` so it always does

Answer (score 2):

The combination of the two answers above:

```
\newcommand{\round}[1]{\ensuremath{\lfloor#1\rceil}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved it this way:

```
\newcommand\round[1]{\left[#1\right]}
```

Then I could use it as a function:

```
$F = \round{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\norm{F_{i}}}$
```

This is the result:

[image: round symbol]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There's a problem with your notation: it can also denote the `floor` of number *x* (the greatest integer *n* <= *x*).

Comment: The present picture is not the result of your code.