# Round command argument before using

Tags: macros

I am new to LaTeX and found a helpful custom command for repeating text n times [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449075/repeating-another-text-multiple-times-using-commands). Below is an example use

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\myrepeat{6}{x}  % prints xxxxxx
\end{document}
```

My goal is to pass a decimal number as the first argument to the command (as opposed to an integer currently). The for-loop in the command should round the decimal to determine how many iterations to execute. This way I can universally change the rounding mode (i.e. floor, ceiling, closest integer, etc) later just by updating the one command. For instance

```
\myrepeat{3.2}{x}  % should print xxx
\myrepeat{3.7}{x}  % should print xxxx
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Most other [threads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433101/rounding-to-nearest-integer-symbol-in-latex) I have seen only deal with printing rounding/ceiling/floor *symbols* instead of actually performing the rounding math and allowing you to use the resulting number in further computations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be this. `ceil` and `floor` are alternatives to `round`. There are also command versions of each, as Alan Munn mentions in a comment, i.e. `\pgfmathround{#1}`, `\pgfmathceil{#1}`, `\pgfmathfloor{#1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{%
   \pgfmathparse{round(#1)}% set rounding function here
   \foreach \n in {1,...,\pgfmathresult}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\myrepeat{3.2}{x}  % should print xxx

\myrepeat{3.7}{x}  % should print xxxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `\pgfmathround{#1}` ... `{1,...,\pgfmathresult}`

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fairly general macro where you can set the mode as an optional argument: choose between `round` (default), `floor`, `ceil` or `nearest`.

The `\generalrepeat` macro accepts the starting point (an integer), the step (an integer, default 1) and the end point (a floating point number).

The `\myrepeat` macro is a reduced version, always starting from 1 with step 1.

In the final argument (code to repeat), the current value in the loop is denoted by `#1`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\generalrepeat}
 {
  O{round} % the mode
  m % the starting point
  O{1} % the step
  m % the final point
  +m % the code to repeat (can contain \par)
 }
 {
  \klinke_repeat_general:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myrepeat}
 {
  O{round} % the mode
  m % the final point
  +m % the code to repeat (can contain \par)
 }
 {
  \klinke_repeat_general:nnnnn { #1 } { 1 } { 1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \klinke_repeat_general:nnnnn
 {
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \__klinke_repeat_mode:n { __klinke_repeat_#1:n }
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__klinke_repeat_code:n { #5 }
  \int_step_function:nnnN
   { #2 } % start
   { #3 } % step
   { \__klinke_repeat_mode:n { #4 } } % end
   \__klinke_repeat_code:n % action
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__klinke_repeat_round:n { \fp_eval:n { round(#1,0,1) } }
\cs_new:Nn \__klinke_repeat_floor:n { \fp_eval:n { floor(#1,0) } }
\cs_new:Nn \__klinke_repeat_ceil:n  { \fp_eval:n { ceil(#1,0) } }
\cs_new:Nn \__klinke_repeat_nearest:n
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 - floor(#1,0) < 0.5 ? floor(#1,0) : ceil(#1,0) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\generalrepeat{1}{3.4}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat{1}{3.5}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat{1}{3.6}{#1 }

\generalrepeat[ceil]{1}{3.4}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[ceil]{1}{3.5}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[ceil]{1}{3.6}{#1 }

\generalrepeat[floor]{1}{3.4}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[floor]{1}{3.5}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[floor]{1}{3.6}{#1 }

\generalrepeat[nearest]{1}{3.4}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[nearest]{1}{3.5}{#1 }---
\generalrepeat[nearest]{1}{3.6}{#1 }

\myrepeat{3.4}{x}---\myrepeat[floor]{3.4}{x}---%
\myrepeat[ceil]{3.4}{x}---\myrepeat[nearest]{3.4}{x}

\myrepeat{3.5}{x}---\myrepeat[floor]{3.5}{x}---%
\myrepeat[ceil]{3.5}{x}---\myrepeat[nearest]{3.5}{x}

\myrepeat{3.6}{x}---\myrepeat[floor]{3.6}{x}---%
\myrepeat[ceil]{3.6}{x}---\myrepeat[nearest]{3.6}{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both `round` and `nearest` integer are implemented to go upward in case of a tie (the 3.5 case).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the expandable functionality of [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,xfp}

\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{\foreach \n in {1,...,\fpeval{floor(#1)}}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\myrepeat{6}{x}                % prints xxxxxx

\myrepeat{3.2}{x}              % prints xxx

\myrepeat{8.1 * sin(pi / 6)}{x}% prints xxxx sin(pi/6) = 1/2; 8.1 * 1/2 = 4.05

\end{document}
```

You can use `ceiling(#1)`, or `round(#1,0)`, or whatever calculation you want.

Comment: The function `round` uses “ties to even”, so both `round(3.5,0)` and `round(4.5,0)` will yield 4. You get “ties to infinity” with `round(3.5,0,1)` or `round(4.5,0,1)` that would yield 4 and 5 respectively.